# What exactly does it mean when $_FILES is empty?

Tags: php, error-handling, upload

I am working on a PHP upload script and when testing my error checks, I attempted to upload a 17MB TIFF file. When I do this the $_FILES array is empty. The script works fine for what I need it to do, which is to upload JPEG files. My solution is to test if $_FILES is empty or not before continuing with the upload script.

Can anybody explain why $_FILES is empty when a TIFF is attempted to be uploaded? Is my solution, to check if $_FILES is empty or not, an okay one?

Does this have something to do with settings in `php.ini`?

**Just to clarify**

I was checking that `$_FILES` was empty using the following:

```
if(empty($_FILES))
{
    die('$_FILES is empty.');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) controls max upload size, which the TIFF file most likely exceeded.  The default is 2M.  You can test with:

```
echo ini_get("upload_max_filesize");
```

EDIT: Actually, the exact cause is more likely  [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size), which is always >= upload_max_filesize:   "If the size of post data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES  superglobals  are empty."

Comment: Thanks! It was definitely because the TIFF file size exceeded both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check to see if `$_FILES['file']['error']` is equal to `0`. This indicates a "success".

If your files array is empty, it might be due to some other problem, like not including the enctype.

Try doing `var_dump($_FILES)` and viewing the contents...

**EDIT**: I know you can set the max filesize in the `php.ini` file, but I am not sure if that will give you an empty files array. I think you will just get an error.

Comment: Good advice. To var_dump an empty array

Comment: @Col - Since he sounds like a beginner, it was to help verify the array is indeed empty, and that he isnt viewing the wrong index.

Answer (score 0):

As posted already, it's empty because if failed. Also check for a form element like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="-maxsizegoeshereinbytes-" />
```

To be extra sure (once you actually have an array - adding to the 'check the error key' post, btw) , you can also check the size

```
if( $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0 ) {

}
```

Comment: That's not true.  Only PHP pays attention to the MAX_FILE_SIZE field.

Comment: Updated answer - thanks for that detail. Though still applicable, as this is php.

Comment: Your answer is still irrelevant

Comment: How? If i try to upload a 40 MB file into a form with <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000" />, even if php has a limit of 100MB, it will still result in an empty $_FILES array.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel. Instead of just stating that something is irrelevant, please explain why.